# Update the dropdown list on AJAX success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropdown, call

I have a Dropdown list where I choose the League and another dropdown which features the teams according to the league selected in the first dropdown. My problem is what to include in the success function of the AJAX Call to update the dropdown list with the selected league. Could anyone help me achieve this. Thanks

**PHP DB Query / view_fixtures_queries.php**

```
$league = '';

if(isset($_POST['selected'])):
   $league = $_POST['selected'];
endif;

$home_team = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE competition = :league");

echo "<script>console.log($league)</script>";

$home_team->execute([ ':league' => $league ]);

$data  = $home_team->fetchAll();

print_r($data);
```

**Fetching Teams in Teams Dropdown List**

```
<?php
   while ($row = $home_team->fetchAll()) 
   {
       $hometeamlogo = $row['logo'];
       $hometeamstadium = $row['stadium'];
       echo "<option value='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode( $hometeamlogo )."' data-stadium='$hometeamstadium'>" . $row['team_name'] . "</option>";
   }
?>
```

**AJAX Call to send the selected league**

```
//input_competition is the league dropdown
$('#input_competition').on('change', function () {
         var selectedLeague = $('#input_competition').find(":selected").text();
           
         $.ajax({
            url: 'queries/view_fixtures_queries.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'selected' : selectedLeague},
            success: function(data) {
                //what to include here
                console.log(data);
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: what does `console.log(data);` giving you show output of that . Also , where you need to add this output ?

Comment: The console.log is displaying nothing the `print_r($data);` is what displays the league chosen as an alert. I need to update the `echo "<option>` of the while loop so that it displays only the teams of the league selected

Comment: But i think the data is being sent to the PHP since `print_r($data);` is showing the correct data when i choose a different league